# Show that the angle with x-axis which the tangent to a circle is -x/y

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

everyone this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OxPv.png) is from Hogben's *Mathematics for the Million*. I'm not sure if I'm even interpreting it correctly, but I'm not making any headway. Any help would be appreciated for either the first or second parts (or both).

I'm interpreting the question as asking for the angle alpha in blue [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhHw0.png), is this incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: This picture may help.
http://keisan.casio.com/keisan/SCM_HP/image_mathnote/mathnote_sinxoverx03.GIF

Comment: I don't really think the question should say the 'angle' the tangent makes. It is really the slope of the tangent line which is equal to the tangent function of the angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any line connecting the origin to a point on a circle will have a slope $\frac{y}{x}$.

The normal line to this line will be a tangent to the circle, and it will have a negative reciprocal slope, $-\frac{x}{y}$.

The angle it will make with the x-axis will be $\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan(\frac{y}{x})$. So, they must mean slope, not angle.

Comment: I'm embarassed at how much time I spent interpreting it as asking for the angle rather than the slope... Thanks!